# What do the different icons in the ladder table mean?

Tags: starcraft-2

Does the up/down arrows mean you are going to go up/down a league?
Do they mean you are advancing/losing inside the division?
What do the other 2 icons (-- and !) mean?

[image]

Is there some visual indication (reference) in that screen I'm missing? (I couldn't find the answer there)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The up and down arrows mean the player/team has changed position in their division since last week. An exclamation mark means the player is new to the division this week, and `--` indicates no change.

Comment: When does the "week" change?

Comment: I would guess Tuesday -- but that's only because Blizz does their World of Warcraft maintenance on that day, which is now hosted on battle.net. No evidence for that though.

Comment: @Juan I believe it's either Sunday or more likely, Monday. I'll try to remember to edit that into my answer when I can confirm.

Answer (score 4):

If you hover over the up or down arrows it'll tell you what rank in the division they were at the end of last week. Hovering over exclamation marks tells you when they joined the division.